# How to make max() take variable as it's argument

Tags: r, ggplot2

In setting the scales of my ggplot, I need to specify `max` and `min` values.

Now everything works fine if I specify the path directly (e.g `x$column`), but I would like it to take an argument containing the path, how can this be achieved?

Code

```
SMAcolName  <- colnames(ov.indicators)[grep("SMAPrice", names(ov.indicators))]
SMAsourceName  <- paste0("ov.indicactors$", SMAcolName)

    line.SMAsqrmPrice  <- ggplot(data = fortify(ov.indicators), aes_string( x = "published", y = SMAcolName )) + 
      geom_line() + 
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(seq(10000, max(SMAsourceName, na.rm = TRUE), by = 5000) )) +
```

The above code gives an error, but demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: use `get(..., envir= "ov.indicators")`. The way you're attempting passes a character string, not a variable name that needs to be interpretted

Comment: I think `"SMAsourcename"` is a string.  I don't have a data.frame named ov.indicators, so I won't check. Please give a [minimal WORKING example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `max(ov.indicators[,"SMAcolName"], na.rm=TRUE)`.

The trick here is that you don't need to use the `$` notation. I'm assuming that ov.indicators is a data.frame or a matrix (or a 2D array). That assumption is based on your use of `colnames`.